# How do I set a date field's default value to the day's date?

Tags: html

I'm building an HTML/ColdFusion page and have a field type of "date". How do I set the value for that field to the day's date that the user is signed on - i.e. the "now" date? It sounds like it should be easy but I can't find a way to make it work. I'm fairly new to coding so please keep answers simple.

Comment: 1. You go look up _what_ value (format) you have to set first, and then 2. You write code to output the current date in that format in the value attribute of the field. // You are supposed to show us what you have already tried when asking here, and “nothing” is a bit too little. Please go read [ask].

Comment: I think you cannot do this with html only. You need to use javascript. See a simple example here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_current

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer using the ColdFusion date format function such as TodaysDate=DateFormat(Now(),"YYYY-MM-DD") and then setting the value to TodaysDate.